# Why rbind converts a list of numeric elements to a character matrix?

Tags: r, rbind

Why does rbind convert my list of numeric elements to character?

```
> class(mymatrix.list)
[1] "list"
> class(mymatrix.list[[1]])
[1] "numeric"
> mymatrix.results = do.call(rbind, mymatrix.list)
> class(mymatrix.results)
[1] "matrix"
> class(mymatrix.results[1])
[1] "character"
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You _should_ have offered `lapply(mymatrix.list, class)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because one of the items in your list contains characters?

```
mymatrix.list <- list()
for(i in 1:10){
  mymatrix.list[[i]] <- rnorm(26)
}

class(mymatrix.list)
# [1] "list"
class(mymatrix.list[[1]])
# [1] "numeric"
mymatrix <- do.call(rbind, mymatrix.list)
class(mymatrix)
# [1] "matrix"
class(mymatrix[1])
# [1] "numeric"

## Add a character vector to your list
mymatrix.list[[11]] <- LETTERS
mymatrix <- do.call(rbind, mymatrix.list)
class(mymatrix)
# [1] "matrix"
class(mymatrix[1])
# [1] "character"
```

Comment: Indeed, a bug in my program. I had one of the elements in the list of character type.

Answer (score 2):

the first arguement of `rbind` is `...` and the help file reads:

```
Arguments:

     ...: vectors or matrices.  These can be given as named arguments.
          Other R objects will be coerced as appropriate: see sections
          ‘Details’ and ‘Value’.  (For the ‘"data.frame"’ method of
          ‘cbind’ these can be further arguments to ‘data.frame’ such
          as ‘stringsAsFactors’.)
```

and the character conversion is likely due to one of your lists containing a character.