# Avoid rbind()/cbind() conversion from numeric to factor

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a dataset before plotting it. I decided to use function factory `gammaplot.ff()` and the first version of my code looks like this:

```
PowerUtility1d <- function(x, delta = 4) {
  return(((x+1)^(1 - delta)) / (1 - delta))
}
PowerUtility1d <- Vectorize(PowerUtility1d, "x")

# function factory allows multiparametrization of PowerUtility1d()
gammaplot.ff <- function(type, gamma) {
  ff <- switch(type, 
               original = function(x) PowerUtility1d(x/10, gamma),
               pnorm_wrong = function(x) PowerUtility1d(2*pnorm(x)-1, gamma),
               pnorm_right = function(x) PowerUtility1d(2*pnorm(x/3)-1, gamma)
              )
  ff
}

gammaplot.df <- data.frame(type=numeric(), gamma=numeric(), 
                           x=numeric(), y=numeric())
gammaplot.gamma <- c(1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2:7)
gammaplot.pts <- (-1e4:1e4)/1e3

# building the data set
for (gm in gammaplot.gamma) {
   for (tp in c("original", "pnorm_wrong", "pnorm_right")) {
     fpts <- gammaplot.ff(tp, gm)(gammaplot.pts)    
     dataChunk <- cbind(tp, gm, gammaplot.pts, fpts)
     colnames(dataChunk) <- names(gammaplot.df)
     gammaplot.df <- rbind(gammaplot.df, dataChunk)
   }
}

# rbind()/cbind() cast all data to character, but x and y are numeric
gammaplot.df$x <- as.numeric(as.character(gammaplot.df$x))
gammaplot.df$y <- as.numeric(as.character(gammaplot.df$y))
```

Turns out, the whole data frame contains character data, so I have to convert it back manually (took me a while to discover that in the first place!). SO search [indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518740/why-rbind-converts-a-list-of-numeric-elements-to-a-character-matrix) that this happens because **type** variable is character. To avoid this (you can imagine performance issues on character data while building the data set!) I changed the code a bit:

```
gammaplot.ff <- function(type, gamma) {
  ff <- switch(type, 
               function(x) PowerUtility1d(x/10, gamma),
               function(x) PowerUtility1d(2*pnorm(x)-1, gamma),
               function(x) PowerUtility1d(2*pnorm(x/3)-1, gamma)
              )
  ff
}

for (gm in gammaplot.gamma) {
  for (tp in 1:3) {
    fpts <- gammaplot.ff(tp, gm)(gammaplot.pts)    
    dataChunk <- cbind(tp, gm, gammaplot.pts, fpts)
    colnames(dataChunk) <- names(gammaplot.df)
    gammaplot.df <- rbind(gammaplot.df, dataChunk)
  }
}
```

This works fine for me, but I lost a self-explanatory character parameter, which is a downside. Is there a way to keep the first version of function factory without an implicit conversion of all data to character?

If there's another way of achieving the same result, I'd be happy to try it out.

Comment: @Thomas, your short answer is clearly wrong; see accepted answer. Also, stating that you shouldn't do something without an alternative is not constructive.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use `rbind.data.frame` and `cbind.data.frame` instead of `rbind` and `cbind`.

Comment: It is even enough to use only `cbind.data.frame`, since `rbind` works correctly (detecing data frame as one of its arguments).
Never thought it'd be so simple!

Comment: Beware: When using `cbind.data.frame()` in combination with names lists, you'll create a n x m matrix, you did not intend. In case, this is not intended, just `unlist()` the named list, before using `cbind.data.frame()` instead of `cbind()`.

Comment: `cbind.data.frame(tp, gm, gammaplot.pts, fpts, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

if you dont have stringsAsFactors = F you can still have factors.

Comment: This was super useful. Had to write my own custom function to do this.

Comment: I had the same problem but cbind.data.frame did not work for me.  I used cbind.data.frame and it still turns numeric columns into character.  Here is a reproducible example....  apply function shows all three columns are character             testdf <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(1,100), 5,),
                     y = rnorm(5))


testdf2 <- cbind.data.frame(testdf, z = sample(c('a','b'), 5, replace = TRUE),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

apply(testdf2,2,class)

Comment: @seakyourpeak: The testdf2 in your example has classes integer, numeric and character as you would expect. However, apply turns everything into a matrix and to do this everything is turned into characters. Try lapply(testdf2, class) instead to figure out the classes.

Comment: Thank you! lt was the apply function giving me wrong results but lapply gave the correct results.

Answer (score 8):

I want to put @mtelesha 's comment to the front.

Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `cbind` or `cbind.data.frame`:

```
x <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5], b = 1:5)
y <- cbind(x, c = LETTERS[1:5])
class(y$c)
## "factor"
y <- cbind.data.frame(x, c = LETTERS[1:5])
class(y$c)
## "factor"
y <- cbind(x, c = LETTERS[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
class(y$c)
## "character"
y <- cbind.data.frame(x, c = LETTERS[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
class(y$c)
## "character"
```

**UPDATE (May 5, 2020):**

As of R version 4.0.0, R uses a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` default in calls to `data.frame()` and `read.table()`.

https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/

Comment: But the number of columns should be the same, otherwise this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I use rbind or rbind.data.frame, the columns are turned into characters every time. Even if I use stringsAsFactors = FALSE. What worked for me was using

```
rbind.data.frame(df, data.frame(ColNam = data, Col2 = data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```