# R understanding why numbers treated as factors, creating dataframe with colSums

Tags: r

I read a txt into R as a dataframe, the numbers are read in as integers. Partial dataset:

```
otu <- structure(list(Otu00002 = c(167L, 808L, 0L, 103L, 245L, 99L, 146L, 395L, 479L, 185L), Otu00003 = c(367L, 563L, 562L, 806L, 726L, 693L, 753L, 1089L, 358L, 938L), Otu00004 = c(281L, 1338L, 634L, 471L, 146L, 46L, 138L, 171L, 400L, 378L), Otu00005 = c(191L, 262L, 234L, 148L, 184L, 278L, 117L, 141L, 118L, 61L), Otu00006 = c(87L, 104L, 99L, 85L, 31L, 57L, 6L, 12L, 80L, 78L), Otu00007 = c(11L, 99L, 32L, 49L, 51L, 54L, 259L, 179L, 65L, 21L), Otu00008 = c(304L, 90L, 36L, 376L, 416L, 210L, 173L, 67L, 108L, 406L), Otu00009 = c(26L, 61L, 531L, 53L, 58L, 438L, 57L, 688L, 546L, 5L), Otu00010 = c(0L, 1L, 182L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 153L, 79L, 350L, 0L)), .Names = c("Otu00002", "Otu00003", "Otu00004", "Otu00005", "Otu00006", "Otu00007", "Otu00008", "Otu00009", "Otu00010"), row.names = c("E04", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E08", "E09", "E10", "E11", "E12", "F01"), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I want to create a dataframe with 2 variables-the column headers of "otu" and column sums. If I create this dataframe through cbind, the column sums (test$size.sub) are treated as factors.

```
test <-as.data.frame(cbind(OTU = colnames(otu), size.sub = (colSums(otu))))
```

Even if I specify as.numeric

```
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(OTU=colnames(otu), size.sub= as.numeric(colSums(otu))))
```

However, if I first create a dataframe with just the colSums then rename that variable and create a second variable of the row.names, temp$size.sub is numeric.

```
temp <- as.data.frame(colSums(otu))
colnames (temp) <- c("size.sub")
temp$OTU <- row.names(sub.size)
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

ETA-I didn't know before this question that cbind was the culprit. Marking this question as dup because I didn't search with the correct terms defeats the purpose of asking questions in the first place-had I known to search for cbind and factors, I would have known the answer. I provided reproducible examples that could help people in the future.

Comment: Because `cbind` returns a matrix and a matrix can't hold mixed classes, hence it's reduces it to lowest possible common class- which is character. While `as.data.frame` converts `character`s to `factor`s by default (historical reasons). All in all, don't use `cbind`. Just do `data.frame(OTU = colnames(otu), size.sub = colSums(otu))` or such.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, post as answer (or find a dupe)?

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535996/avoid-rbind-cbind-conversion-from-numeric-to-factor ? dunno

Comment: I tried making just a dataframe first (same syntax as you suggest) and get this error "Error in as.data.frame(OTU = colnames(otu), size.sub = colSums(otu)) :   argument "x" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Welp. you used `as.data.frame`, not `data.frame`- there is a difference. You could just copy the code snipped I posted.

Comment: did not know there was a difference. now it works